# Ionic 4 Tabs TypeError: Cannot read property ‘querySelectorAll’ of null at getBackButton

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

I'm getting this Error when using Child Routes and Tabs.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null at getBackButton
```

starting from here will open the first child route to another info page
**detail.page.html**

```
<ion-item button lines="none" [routerLink]="['details']">More</ion-item>
```

**detail-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component:DetailPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'details',
                component: DetailInfosPage
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**detail-infos.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button color="secondary"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Extra Infos</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab-bar slot="top">
            <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
                <ion-label>Infos</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>

            <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
                <ion-label>Infos 2</ion-label>
                <ion-badge>6</ion-badge>
            </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

**detail-infos-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'details',
        component: DetailInfosPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tab1',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'tab2',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'details/tab1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

After clicking

```
<ion-item button lines="none" [routerLink]="['details']">More</ion-item>
```

the Error is thrown, but child page with Tabs is loaded but none of the Tabs is active

So what do i'm missing here?

Comment: Can you do a stackblitz with your case ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that a commit caused a [regression](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/commit/71875417f207d26bd7115655f239251460a1e3d8).
The Solution is not to use "@ionic/angular@5.0.2"
This Version works "@ionic/angular@5.0.1".

[See also here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-tabs-typeerror-cannot-read-property-queryselectorall-of-null-at-getbackbutton/184120/3)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same issue:

```
[ng] [console.error]: {
[ng]   "line": 48,
[ng]   "column": 32,
[ng]   "sourceURL": "http://localhost:8100/ios-transition-b4752795-js.js"
[ng] }
```

Going through that `ios-transition-...js` file pointed me in the direction of some `getBackButton()` call that was apparantly calling it. (This led me nowhere.)

The reason this was happening was because of a *manual* transition on the component that has the tabs. The `<ion-tabs>` component has a built-in router and this should automatically take you where you need to go.

After taking out my manual state transition (router.navigate) the error was gone.

I hope this helps!